# SwiftUI | Drag and Drop using LazyVGrid?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode12

Is it possible to reorder the items inside the LazyVGrid using drag and drop?

Like something similar to the Editmode when using a List together with .onMove()?

Thanks!

Comment: Posted demo solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid

Answer (score 2):

According to an [Apple Engineer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650137):

> That's not built-today, though you can use the `View.onDrag(_:)` and
> `View.onDrop(...)` to add support for drag and drop manually.
>
> Do file a feedback request if you'd like to see built-in reordering
> support. Thanks!

So unfortunately we are on our own here. :/

Have you tried this?
[SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

Comment: It's funny how all of these questions you mentioned are mine haha. I have tried this, I didn't succeed, however, Asperi has, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid

Comment: Haha!  Thanks for the link!